# Custom method for getting a gem inside Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

When we're building our apps using a custom Gem we have to keep making amendments to our Gemfile to point at either our local code, our shared server (using geminabox) or when in production we use a version of the gem unpacked (as our gem server is vpn protected).

This means we have code like this in our gemfile:

```
# QA and Bamboo
gem 'our_gem', '0.0.1', source: 'https://gems.website.com'
# Development, Test
#gem 'our_gem', path: "../our_gem"
# Production
#gem 'our_gem', path: "../vendor/gems/our_gem-0.1.1"
```

And our developers have to keep commenting and uncommenting each line before they do a push to a branch for building on Bamboo, etc.

One proposal was to replace it with a custom method like:

```
custom_gem 'our_gem', '0.1.1'
```

in place of the `gem` declaration in the Gemfile.

Which would be:

```
def custom_gem(name, version = '0.0.1')
  case Rails.env
  when qa?, :bamboo?
    gem name, version, source: 'https://gems.website.com'
  when development?, test?
    gem name, path: "../#{name}"
  when production?
    gem name, path: "../vendor/gems/#{name}-#{version}"
  else
    fail "Unknown environment for gem: #{name}"
  end
end
```

The question is... can you use custom methods like this inside a Gemfile? and if so where would this code live within an application. Or would we have to resort to using something like: http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#INSTALL_IF

Comment: can't you just use [bundler groups](http://bundler.io/v1.12/groups.html)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If we used Groups we'd have to make sure the bundle installs were set to exclude the others. It'd be more code and not very clean. The comment methodology would work better. What we're looking for is a way to purely use the environment to dictate the gem install.

Comment: @Cameron but that is what groups are for e.g. `gem our_gem, "0.0.1", source: 'https://gems.website.com', group: [:qa,:bamboo]` and `gem our_gem, path: "../our_gem", group: [:development,:test]`

Comment: @engineersmnky yes but we're wanting to install based on environment rather than not install based on environment. If we used groups we'd have to do `bundle install --without production qa bamboo` for our development. Just wondered if we could build something that would be easier if we could tailor it the reverse. We do use that command on our CI server to exclude dev and test gems but that's automated, where as our team is using terminal, etc, to do the bundle so they'd have to remember to exclude or setup an alias hence why they've opted for the comments approach.

Comment: It'd be better if Bundler supported something like groups whereby gems were installed based on their environment rather than having to manually exclude those in other groups. Which is essentially what we're trying to see if we can achieve.

Comment: @Cameron but `bundler` does not have an environment `rails` does. Just because you are bundling does not mean you are using `rails` so what would environment mean in this case?

Comment: You can wrap your custom_gem method with commands from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/adamjmurray/3154437). Give it a try.

Comment: @engineersmnky So in our case our custom method would be the best way forward... but are we able to use custom methods inside Gemfiles?